# detecting decorated function in module

Tags: python, python-decorators, introspection

I have a source for a python module, and I want to find a specific function (function, not a class, not a method in a class etc.. ) in the module.
That function will be decorated with a specific decorator (which has open list of perameters, as its' parameters depend on the function decorated).

Note that the function will *not* be run.

I can of course create the AST from the source, and look there, but TBH it's quite painful.
Is there a way where I can load the module and inspect the functions to find whether it's decorated? I also need to get at the time the parameters of the decorator and the signature decorated function.

The use case is that I want to define an entry function in the module, and also provide some more information on the method (which cannot be captured by simple typing) and present in some sort of UI to the users that function and all the information about it (from its signature + the data in the decorator). The decorator's role is also to check those bits at the runtime..

Going back to the simple case say I have a parametric decorator:

```
def main_function(*ef_args, **ef_kwargs):
    def inner_dec(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # use ef_args, ef_kwargs
            response = f(args, kwargs)
            return response
        return wrapped
    return inner_decorator
```

and then a function in a module file (assume the decorator above is imported):

```
@main_function(type2="MyFrame", result1="somethign..", result2="somethingelse")
def my_main(param1: string, param2: Frame):
    ....
```

When I try via inspect, I can see the my_main, but can't see how to tell it's decorated with my decorator, and its signature always comes across as the signature of the decorator.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) through the source for `@` (or a more fitting regex)? Or do you want to detect at runtime whether the currently executing function has been decorated?

Comment: Can you edit the decorator? Because it seems that would be the easiest way to keep track of decorated functions.

Comment: @Jens - because I need to get out more information than just existence, so would still have to parse the result and parse it in python. I could use AST, but I'm keeping that as a last resort

Comment: @Jasmijn, yes, the decorator is under my control. But the decorator will only run when the function is invoked, and I'm need to present the information before it's invoked. If it was post-invoke, it'd easy, I'd just get the info from the decorator and register it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your decorator like so:

```
import functools
def main_function(*ef_args, **ef_kwargs):
    def inner_dec(f):
        # this makes sure that `wrapped` looks like `f`
        # in terms of signature:
        @functools.wraps(f) 
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # use ef_args, ef_kwargs
            response = f(args, kwargs)
            return response
        register_my_function(wrapped) # this registers your function
        return wrapped
    return inner_decorator
```

... this should register all functions decorated with `main_function` at import time, and behaves the same at call time.

(Implementation of `register_my_function` left up to the reader.)

Comment: ah, I see. I guess I didn't understand the decorators properly (when are they executed).  Thanks!